# Postgres postgis failed to re-find parent key in index for deletion target page

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgis

I have problem with GiST index and autovacuum. My pg_log contains many errors

> ERROR:  failed to re-find parent key in index for "%TABLE" deletion target page
>
> > CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table

Why it may happens?

Postgres - 9.1.14

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/22660.1283019161@sss.pgh.pa.us might help. Have you tried reindex or dropping and recreating it.

Comment: It temporary solution - i can't do it every 2 days. I wanna avoid this problem(I have regular auto vacuum)

Comment: Yes, sure, but the suggestion in that thread is that reindex will fix it, that it is a one off corruption.

Comment: Unfortunately index corrupted regularly =(

Comment: I think you will need to give more information about table structure, indexes, etc, to get any more help. Perhaps better on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the only question on this error (failed to re-find parent key in index for deletion target page) on stackoverflow, I will add my answer here, which worked for me.

I had the same error in logs after autovacuum, but not in the system tables and the error did not occur again after reindexing without taking any locks.

It took literally two seconds for my table and the error did not appear in the logs after reindexing.

```
REINDEX TABLE CONCURRENTLY your_table_name;
```